# SQLite FTS3 - Full-Text Search over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3

I have a `brand_name` column in my `brand_names` table and a `product_name` column in my `product_names` table.

At the moment, I have two separate SELECTs (one on `brand_names.brand_name` and one on `product_names.product_name`) and I use a UNION to OR the two resultsets together. However, when a search is made for "SomeBrandName Some Product Name", even though such a product exists, my SQL returns zero results (this is because the terms - `SomeBrandName` `Some` `Product` and `Name` - don't *all* appear in `brand_names.brand_name` and they don't *all* appear in `product_names.product_name`).

So I need help to work out SQLite / FTS3 equivalent of something like...

`SELECT
    (brand_names.brand_name || ' ' || product_names.product_name) AS brand_and_product_name
FROM
    brand_names, product_names
WHERE
    brand_and_product_name MATCH 'SomeBrandName Some Product Name'`

What is the actual SQLite / FTS3 SQL that I need to achieve this?

In terms of research, I have read through the [SQLite FTS3 guide](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) but it doesn't mention multiple tables.

I've also seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267676/sqlite3-multiple-fts-tables-search) which is a bit more advanced and so may well be overkill for the simple search I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

For that you must have to prepare first virtual tables for both of your tables . 
Then you can apply indexed search(FTS Search) on them using join same as you use join with simple table .

Answer (score 0):

An FTS search can be done only in FTS indexes.

If you want to have a result for "Brand Product", you have to create an FTS table that contains these words in a single row.
(To reduce storage, try using an [external content table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2_2) on a view.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I have now shifted the brand_name column into the same table as the product_name column. Do you know how I can do a FTS query over both columns? (Found nothing that helps here - http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html .

Comment: Thema documentation you linked says that MATCH can take the table name instead of a column name.